# Etymology of ぐるぐる

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, japanese

Since it's written in Hiragana, I presume it is likely not a recent loan word. However, its pronounciation bears resemblance to "軲轆", a Mandarin word meaning wheel--similar to ぐるぐる's meaning of "round" or "round-and-round".

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BB%B2%E8%BD%86), the etymology of "軲轆" is apparently quite ancient, deriving from Tibetan or even Proto-Indo-European. Does ぐるぐる also share Proto-Indo-European roots (despite Japanese not being part of that language family)?

Comment: Is there a reason to think it's not an ideophone?

Comment: 軲轆 gūlu [kʰulu] (Mandarin, colloquial) 1. wheel; 2. to roll. ぐるぐる [ɡɯ̟ᵝɾɯ̟ᵝɡɯ̟ᵝɾɯ̟ᵝ] "turning round and round". Do you really mean the two words really sound similar? Did you know that all those Japanese reduplicated 2×2 syllable words always spelled in Hiragana are onomatopoeia, sound symbolism, words that phonetically imitate, resemble, or suggest the sound, the feeling, or a thing that it describes. Have you read this article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_sound_symbolism

Comment: This should be asked at the [japanese.se] site. :)

Comment: I'd say it's on-topic here.

Comment: Is there evidence that the similarity is entirely coincidental? If ぐるぐる is onomatopoeia, does 軲轆 also share certain onomatopoeic roots? It does not seem objectively obvious that something turning makes a “guruguru” or ‘gulu” sound. What I’m interested in is whether there is a connection in the onomatopoeia itself, assuming that it is entirely onomatopoeic.

Comment: @YellowSky Mandarin _gūlu_ is not [kʰulu] but [ku˥lu], and as a Japanese loan word, the expected outcome would indeed be グル. As a verb, the Mandarin verb is commonly reduplicated as well. So yes, they sound very similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chinese *gūlu* < **kʰaːroːɡ* is probably not onomatopoeic, especially if it came from (PIE) **kʷékʷlos* "wheel" (related to English "circle") as Bauer suggests.

Japanese *guruguru* "round and round" is standard onomatopoeic reduplication, like *boroboro* "old and tattered", *wakuwaku* "excited" etc. It's not very old at all; the oldest citation in the Kokugo Daijiten is 1672 (in *guruguru-wage*, a wrapped bun hairstyle).

*guruguru* must be related to *gururi* (1603) and *kururi* (1151), both with a meaning of "turning around, going around".  An intermediate form may be *kururi-kururi* (ca. 14c) by dropping the *-ri*, cf. *guru-tto* < *gururi-to*. The morpheme in *meguru* (8c), "surround, go around", is probably the same, and with normal Japanese vowel mutation, also the one in *korogaru* "roll", *koro-koro* "rollingly" etc. (note *kururi* and *korogaru* are written with the same kanji, 転, Mandarin *zhuǎn*).

In summary, *guru-guru* is a late instance of a whole family of Japanese words circling around a core morpheme *kuru/koro*, with the meaning of "around, round and round, roll".

A connection of this productive "around" morpheme to Chinese **kʰaːroːɡ* "wheel" (and thus to PIE) cannot be discarded, but I don’t think there’s any concrete evidence for it.  The old Japanese orthographies for this morpheme didn’t use the characters 軲轆, but rather kana, or semantic characters like 回.  This means that, if *kuru* comes from **kʰaːroːɡ*, the transmission would have to have been ancient and prehistoric, so that by the point writing arrives, the connection was not apparent to Japanese speakers anymore.

Another possibility is that *kuru* is a native J morpheme but its productivity was later reinforced by *gūlu* in some form.  But again, if that happened, I would expect more historical writers to have represented it with 軲轆 (or at least 轆 *-ro/-ru*, which is used in Japanese, marginally); but that didn't happen.